# Return all objects in an array containing consecutive numbers - Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I would like a function in javascript that can return all objects containing consecutive numbers.
For example...

```
const myObjs = [
{number: 1},
{number: 2},
{number: 3},
{number: 5},
{number: 7},
{number: 10},
{number: 11}
]
```

Running the function on myObjs should return...

```
const result = [
{number: 1},
{number: 2},
{number: 3},
{number: 10},
{number: 11}
]
```

Can anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the predecessor or successor object if in sequence.

```js
const
    data = [{ number: 1 }, { number: 2 }, { number: 3 }, { number: 5 }, { number: 7 }, { number: 10 }, { number: 11 }],
    result = data.filter(({ number }, i, a) =>
        a[i - 1]?.number === number - 1 ||
        number + 1 === a[i + 1]?.number
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, had something rather more clunky. This is nicer